# Partial Keyword Search and Ranking

Tags: django, postgresql

Using Django and Postgres, I have an investment holding model like so:

```
class Holding(BaseModel):    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=16, db_index=True)
    fund_codes = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=16), blank=True, default=list)
    ...
```

That contains a list of approximately 70k US/CAN equity, mutual funds.  I want to build an autocomplete search function that prioritizes 1) ranking of exact match of the `symbol` or `fund_codes`, followed by 2) Near matches on the `symbol`, then 3) Full text search of holding `name`.

If I have a search vector that adds more weight to the `symbol` and `fund_codes`:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector, SearchQuery, SearchRank
from django.db.models import F, Func, Value

vector = SearchVector('name', weight='D') + \
         SearchVector('symbol', weight='A') + \
         SearchVector(Func(F('fund_codes'), Value(' '), function='array_to_string'), weight='A')
```

Then, searching 'MA'

```
Investment.objects \
    .annotate(document=vector, rank=SearchRank(vector, query)) \
    .filter(document__icontains='MA') \
    .order_by('-rank') \
    .values_list('name', 'fund_codes', 'symbol', 'rank',)
```

Doesn't give the results I need.  I need MA (Mastercard) as top listing, Then MAS (Masco Corp), etc... Then listings containing 'MA' in the `name` field.

I've also looked at overriding `SearchQuery` with:

```
class MySearchQuery(SearchQuery):
    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        params = [self.value]
        if self.config:
            config_sql, config_params = compiler.compile(self.config)
            template = 'to_tsquery({}::regconfig, %s)'.format(config_sql)
            params = config_params + [self.value]
        else:
            template = 'to_tsquery(%s)'
        if self.invert:
            template = '!!({})'.format(template)
        return template, params
```

But still not getting results I need. Any suggestions on how I should approach search functionality in this use case?  Perhaps concatenate an exact search query  and a full-text search query?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to pass in normalization parameter. This will give higher ranking to names that are exact match. Raw query looks like following:

```
SELECT id, name, symbol, func_codes, 
ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector(func_codes), to_tsquery('MA'), 2 ) as rank 
FROM Holding
ORDER BY rank DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

Notice that I passed in a normalization parameter https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-RANKING

---

How to do it in Django?

I believe that django doesn't yet support passing normalization yet. I see a open ticket for it, but its 2 years old. Maybe no one has worked on it yet.
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28194

You can use raw query for now. See official documentation on how: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/sql/